# It puts strings together instead of adding them Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var x = e.pageX;
var myX = $(this).html();
var difference = myX - x;
var ex = myX + difference;
```

Everything workes until the last row. It doesn´t make an addition, it puts together the variables into one string. If myX is 10 and difference is 20 it will be 1020 when I want it to be 30.

How do I solve this?

Comment: i think you might need a parseInt in there somewhere

Comment: @benhowdle89 Why should we assume that the numbers will be integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the variables to be integer using something like this :

```
var ex = parseInt(myX, 10) + parseInt(difference, 10);
```

This happen because your variables are considered as strings, and using the + operator on strings concatenates then togheter instead of adding their numeric values.

Comment: Looks like not if they get concatened as string.

Comment: `myX` is a string, but `difference` is a number.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue when trying to add a number to a string in Javascript. I think it was an oversight in the design of a dynamic language to use the same operator for addition and string concatenation.

I typically use this trick to get around it:

```
var ex = myx - 0 + difference
```

because subtracting something from a string will convert it to a number.

As Felix pointed out in the comments below, you can use the unary `+` operator to convert a string to a number, like this:

```
var ex = +myx + difference
```

Comment: You can also use unary plus which is easier to understand imo: `+myx + difference`

Comment: @Felix Cool! I'm going to use that next time I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `myX` is a string and it is *concatenating* the numbers together into a new string.

What you need is to change myX into a `number`.

Use `parseInt` to do this.

`parseInt(myX, 10)`

Comment: How do I make it an integer instead?

Answer (score 0):

A minus will force the variables to be parsed as an int but the plus will simply function as concatenation and even coerce the int to a string.